# Javascript portion of my webpage isn't working

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I was writing a very simple webpage with javascript, and I came across something I couldn't understand. Comparatively, I copied code from w3schools about form validation, and tried to integrate it with my work. However, mine isn't working, and I honestly don't know why. If just doesn't run, anyones help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Here is the javascript code </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateform() {
 var x = document.body.forms["example"]["firstname_"].value;
 document.write("testing okay...made it into the function.");

 if( x == NULL || x == "") {

    document.write("testing okay it came into the if statement...Good.");
    alert("Sorry, you didn't enter in the correct information");
 }
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="example" onsubmit="return validateform( )"  method="post" > 

 <input type="text" name="firstname_"> 
 <input type="submit" value="Enter Information">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.write` will surely break your page, use `alert` or `console.log` instead.

Comment: Okay, away from that do you find anything else wrong? Again, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things here:

1. `var x = document.body.forms["example"]["firstname_"].value;`
2. `document.write`
3. `NULL`

The forms property does not exist on `body` use:

```
 var x = document.forms["example"]["firstname_"].value;
```

using `document.write` when the page is already loaded will cause a new document to be written, replacing the current one, thus breaking your page.

`NULL` will also throw an error since it's undefined use `null` in lowercase.

**Why was your code not executing**; because `document.body.forms` threw an error, halting further script execution.

You can easily debug such errors by yourself by using the build in development tools present in all major browsers. You can bring them up with <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it by using the gray `v` under the voting buttons of my answer.